# Why markdown widget is not displayed with django-markdown in django-admin backend?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I'm making a Blog app in Django and want to add Django-Markdown Field in Admin site for Posts model which holds data for blog posts.

What changes need I to do in the following code?

I am using Django:2.2.4 and Django-Markdown-App: 0.9.6

Here is my Post Model

```py
ONE = 1
TWO = 2

status_choices = (
    (ONE, 'draft'),
    (TWO, 'published')
)


class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    content = MarkdownField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=status_choices, default=ONE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Post"
        verbose_name_plural = "Posts"
```

Here is admin.py code

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Posts
from django_markdown.admin import MarkdownModelAdmin


# Register your models here.
class PostsAdmin(MarkdownModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}


admin.site.register(Posts, PostsAdmin)
```

Here is settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
......,
'django_markdown',
......,
]
MARKDOWN_EDITOR_SKIN = 'markitup'
```

Here is Project level urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
.......
 path('markdown/', include('django_markdown.urls')),
.......
]
```

I am expecting to display a markdown interface in the admin site instead of a simple text field, but the current output is a simple text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the jQuery script cannot be found. Can you try with this custom adminModel ?

```
from django_markdown.admin import MarkdownModelAdmin

class PostsAdmin(MarkdownModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}

    class Media:
        js = (
            'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js',  # adds jquery script
        )

admin.site.register(Posts, PostsAdmin)
```

(Something is blocking the access to the django-admin Jquery, usually it can be used with the object [`django.jQuery`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#jquery))

Comment: But brother it's not providing the preview after writing the markdown. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I need to check if the package includes that. Maybe open the console in your browser to check if any error message can help here

Comment: oh yes it's giving this error **POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/markdown/preview/ 403 (Forbidden)** when i click for preview button in django admin view

Comment: I think like js there is need to specify CSS for this but not getting how to do this?

Comment: I think the preview cannot be loaded without a fix in the package django-markdown-app : the ajax call is blocked (403 error) because the `crsftoken` seems to be undefined at the time it is called to setup the ajax handler. This can be fixed if this setup is launched after the page is loaded. BTW, the dirty workaround of my answer could be avoided by using the jQuery version provided in the admin backend (`django.jQuery`), but it's something to fix in the package too. I think you should open an issue on the github project to implement a global fix. Let me know if you need more details ;)

Comment: Thanks, I got it.